# Usage of the "Infinitivo pessoal composto"

Tags: português-brasileiro, português-europeu

I understand that the personal infinitive in Portuguese is generally used when the infinitive has its own subject, different from that of the main verb. And the "Infinitivo pessoal composto" abides by the same rule but expresses already completed actions.

However, I have run into loads of examples where the "Infinitivo pessoal composto" is used but seemingly not abiding by said rule.

> Queria ter estudado no primeiro ano.
>
> Deverias ter visto como foi criado.

In both of these examples, more obviously in the first one, the subject of both verbs is the same.

So, I was wondering if there was any additional rule for the "Infinitivo pessoal composto" because I couldn't find anything to justify its use in this way

Comment: There is only one subject in both those sentences. Wherever did you find that rule? I

Comment: Please answer my question. I have worked hard to answer yours. //@Schilive recommend does not take to.

Comment: @Schilive I recommend you read this. No to.

Comment: The premise of the question is wrong. That infinitive is not personal. Compare: eu gostei de ter estado na praia with eu gostei de teres estado na praia.